# Android WebView don't show html document

Tags: android, webview

I have a html document, I've already tested on the html editor online website (http://htmledit.squarefree.com), it worked fine. However, WebView on android don't show this document, it only show text plain. I have very little experience with html, can anyone help me?

Comment: post some of your html code, java code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your AndroidManifest.xml file includes

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

just after the

```
 <uses-sdk />
```

tag. Without this, your app won't be able to access the Internet and therefore webview won't load anything.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

This will enable javascript